# Understanding Equal Earth Projection (EPSG:8857)

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, equal-area, equal-earth-projection

I am considering using the Equal Earth Projection (EPSG:8857) in a project because it seems to meet the requirements I am after.

If I understand correctly, because this is an *equal-area* projection that means: When I take a 100m² polygone in that projection, e.g. a 10mx10m square, then it is going to be a 100m² area anywhere on earth. And in the example of the 10mx10m square, it won't necessarily stay in the shape of a square but may be distorted because it is not a *conformal* projection.

Is this correct?